# Using table type param in SQL server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use  table type param (@listdraftIds) and split data in table to compare with data in DB but the error is as below. Help me, thank you.

```
 CREATE OR ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sel_contract]
    (
        @listDraftId  nvarchar(max),
        @Page int,
        @PageNumber int,
        @TotalRecord int OUTPUT
    )
        AS
        BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        BEGIN
        DECLARE @listdraftIds TABLE (draftIds nvarchar(max))
        INSERT INTO @listdraftIds VALUES(@listDraftId)

        DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
        SET @sql= ' ALTER DATABASE '+ quotename(db_name()) + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130 ';
        EXEC(@sql)

        END

        DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @newquery NVARCHAR(MAX)

        DECLARE @RowIndex int 
        SET @RowIndex = (@Page-1) * @PageNumber

        SET @query = ''

        SET @query = @query + ' SELECT DISTINCT'
        SET @query = @query + ' [d].[draft_id], '
        ...

        SET @query = @query + 'WHERE '
        SET @query = @query + ' [d].[del_flg] = ''FALSE'''

        SET @query = @query + 'AND '
        SET @query = @query + ' [d].[draft_id]  '
        SET @query = @query + 'IN ('
        SET @query = @query + ' SELECT  DISTINCT  '
        SET @query = @query + ' value AS draft_id '
        SET @query = @query + 'FROM '
        SET @query = @query + ' @listdraftIds '
        SET @query = @query + 'CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(draftIds, '','') '
        SET @query = @query + 'WHERE '
        SET @query = @query + ' RTRIM(value) <> '''' )'

        PRINT  @query

        SET @newquery = '  SET @TotalRecord = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' + @query +') AS t) '

        SET @newquery = @newquery + ' ORDER BY '
        SET @newquery = @newquery + '    [draft_date] DESC, [d].[draft_id] DESC, [g].[detail_no] ASC'
        SET @newquery = @newquery + '    OFFSET @RowIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageNumber ROWS ONLY'  

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @newquery,
            @listDraftId = @listDraftId,
            @RowIndex = @RowIndex,
            @PageNumber = @PageNumber, 
            @TotalRecord = @TotalRecord OUTPUT
    END

Then Exec proc:

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TotalRecord int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_sel_draft_condition_api1]
        @listDraftId = N'123,345',
        @Page = 1,
        @PageNumber = 20,
        @TotalRecord = @TotalRecord OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecord as N'@TotalRecord'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near '30302'.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>       Must declare the table variable "@listdraftIds".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>       Must declare the scalar variable "@PageNumber".

Comment: do a `PRINT @newquery` and check the query

Comment: Consider using a temp table and/or derived query and/or native UDF-to-split instead of dynamic SQL: it leads to significantly easier to understand code and avoids injection - and 'oopsie' - issues. (There doesn't appear to be an immediate need for dynamic SQL: dynamic SQL is only "required" if the schema/query *shape* changes.)

Comment: Print the @newquery and add to the question so that will easy to understand for us

Comment: @A.Goutam don't add additional content to your question in the form of an answer as it isn't an answer to the question. Instead, use the post's [edit] link to edit the original question and add it there.

Comment: Now i have a closer at your dynamic query ? I don't see a need to use dynamic query at all. You can achieve what you want with normal query

Answer (score 0):

few issue here with the stored procedure

First, `sp_executesql` execute in its own context. So variable declared outside of it is not recognized. Which means, if you need to use a variable, you need to pass it into `sp_executesql`.

Your sp_executesql statement does not defined any variable

it should be

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @newquery, 
                      N'@RowIndex int, @PageNumber int, @TotalRecord int OUTPUT',
                      @RowIndex    = @RowIndex,
                      @PageNumber  = @PageNumber, 
                      @TotalRecord = @TotalRecord OUTPUT
```

Note that I didn't include the `@listDraftId`. That is because you can't pass a table variable into `sp_executesql`. One alternative is to use a temp table

So in your `sp_sel_contract`

```
create table #listdraftId ( draftIds nvarchar(max) )
```

And then you can reference the temp table `#listdraftId` in you dynamic query

Actually looking at your dynamic query, you don't required a table variable or temp table. You only have one value of `@listDraftId` that is pass into `sp_sel_contract` and then it is pass into the dynamic query. So you can pass that variable directly into the dynamic query. Example :

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @newquery, 
                  N'@listDraftId nvarchar(max), @RowIndex int, @PageNumber int, @TotalRecord int OUTPUT',
                  @listDraftId = @listDraftId,
                  @RowIndex    = @RowIndex,
                  @PageNumber  = @PageNumber, 
                  @TotalRecord = @TotalRecord OUTPUT
```

EDIT : 
Now i have a closer look at your dynamic query ? I don't see a need to use dynamic query at all. You can achieve what you want with normal query